# Load custom TikZ nodes from an SVG file?

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes, svg, shapes, tikz-shape

I want to use custom nodes in TikZ, with shapes loaded (or otherwise converted) from an SVG file because I don't have enough time to learn `pgf` to draw the shapes I want.  **How can I do that?**

Comment: If you turn them into a suitable format, you can use `\includegraphics{<file>}` inside a `\node` e.g. `\node {\includegraphics{<file>}};`. If you just need them as content i.e. pictures. Probably best to convert them to PDF (unless you're using `latex` via DVI). Of course, the shapes won't be nodes in the sense of having shape-specific handling. If you put an octagon shape in a circular node, the borders of the node will be on the edges of the circle - not the octagon. But you can always place coordinates relative to the images, if necessary, and connect to those etc.

Comment: No good, because I also want to have text in these nodes (and I don't want to write the text inside the SVG).

Comment: Although very brief, have you had a look the `svg.path` library from the PGF/Ti*k*Z manual (http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#SVG-Path Library)?  By using that, you may be able to declare new shapes (http://ctan.unsw.edu.au/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf#declaring new shapes).

PS: The urls in the parenthesis *do* contain spaces.  This is not a mistake (though I can't seem to get markdown to accept that).

Comment: To me seems to more simple to look in manual  for available shapes (you already use TikZ) and it from scratch than make all needed transformation from SVG.

Comment: @JP-Ellis Who created the site was wrong about putting the spaces in. Anyway, add `+` or `%20` where there's supposed to be a space. (Not sure which one is more indicated in this case.)

Comment: @Alenanno The `+` or `%20` don't work... I don't know why though.  This may be a browser-specific thing given that they are argument given to the PDF viewer?

Answer (score 3):

There is an svg2tikz extension for inkscape available from

https://github.com/kjellmf/svg2tikz

I haven't tried it personally so no example here. Jake has an example on site at

https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/245839/1090

Comment: This doesn't answer the question as far as I can tell because you can't create new *node types* this way, can you? Or have I misunderstood the question or the extension or both?

Comment: @cfr not sure really but anyway even if manual editing is required afterwards converting the svg to (any) tikz is perhaps a useful first step.  It is currently the only suggested answer, if someone posts a better answer and this proves to be misleading, I'm happy to delete

Comment: I think this is probably the best answer there is, because I don't think there is a way of doing what the OP wants. As I understand it, defining new kinds of nodes is a bit tricky (which is why `pic`s are so much easier) and I don't think it can be automated in the way that reproducing the shape can be. [I think this may be why the OP says specifically they don't want to learn *PGF* as opposed to TikZ.]

Answer (score 0):

This is supported with graphics converted to `.png` or `.jpg`, by `pgfdeclareimage` and standard `tikz` features. Let me share an example where I build a graph with Lego nodes to visualize the BERTopic model architecture:

```
\documentclass{standalone} 

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\pgfdeclareimage[width=4cm, height=2.5cm]{lego}{figures/lego-piece.png}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (embed) [label=center:\texttt{all-MiniLM-L6-v2}] {\pgfuseimage{lego}};
\node [right=1 cm of embed] {sentence embedding};
\node (reduce) [above=-0.85cm of embed, label=center:\texttt{PCA}] {\pgfuseimage{lego}};
\node [right=1 cm of reduce] {dimensionality reduction};
\node (cluster) [above=-0.85cm of reduce, label=center:\texttt{KMeans}] {\pgfuseimage{lego}};
\node [right=1 cm of cluster] {clustering};
\node (countvect) [above=-0.85cm of cluster, label=center:\texttt{CountVectorizer}] {\pgfuseimage{lego}};
\node [right=1 cm of countvect] {tokenizing};
\node (weight) [above=-0.85cm of countvect, 
label=center:\texttt{c-TF-IDF}] {\pgfuseimage{lego}};
\node [right=1 cm of weight] {weighting schema};
\draw [<-] (weight) edge (countvect) (countvect) edge (cluster) (cluster) edge (reduce) (reduce) edge (embed) ;
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Gives this nice output (which can be further improved):
[image]